# Which files required for qt 5.4 qwebchannel linux deployment?

Tags: linux, qt, deployment, qtwebengine

All,

Have a QtWebEngine based application which uses all local html and javascript files. When deploying this to a test environment the Web page comes up and is navigable, but, webchannel based things aren't working. Everything is fine on development. Problem only happens on deployment to test machine.

This is a self contained .deb which installs creating a user and is meant to bring everything along with it. While it is running on a desktop, there is no network connection, everything is inside.

That said, if "everything" was inside the webchannel would be working. Does anyone have a link identifying what external pieces webchannel requires? There are only two oddities starting up on the target.

```
[0629/132921:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(286)] locale_file_path.empty()
[0629/132921:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(286)] locale_file_path.empty()
```

Trust me, I've surfed for that. There are *thousands* of posts `flagging resource_bundle.cc` throwing `local_file_path.empty()` errors at all kinds of lines and nothing offered as a solution. I am making the grand assumption when webchannel supporting files are identified and placed/pointed to, these will go away and life will be good.

`qwebchannel.js` is deployed, but, maybe there is an environment variable I need to set? the index.html file references qwebchannel.js exactly where it is.

Anyone have the list/link of what files are required when deploying something using qwebchannel.js? It isn't throwing up an error which identifies much.
Thanks,